# expression must have class type: c++ passing instance variable object as a pointer (dot notation parameter)

Tags: c++

I've been looking for an answer for 2 days; I'm at a complete loss.

I've got...

```
struct shipDef
{ 
    int mBaseHealth; 

    b2BodyDef mBodyDef;
};
```

...and in another file...

```
b2Body* b2World::CreateBody(const b2BodyDef* def)
{
   //...
}
```

...and also...

```
shipDef * Game::getShipDef(const char* shipDefID)    
{    
    std::pair<std::multimap<std::string,shipDef*>::iterator, std::multimap<std::string,shipDef*>::iterator> iteratorPair = mShipDefMap.equal_range(shipDefID);

    std::size_t shipDefIDSize = std::distance( iteratorPair.first, iteratorPair.second );
    std::size_t randomSoundIndex = std::rand() % shipDefIDSize;
    std::advance( iteratorPair.first, randomSoundIndex );

    return iteratorPair.first->second;    
}
```

I'm calling...

```
mPhysicsBody = physicsWorld->CreateBody(Game::getInstance()->getShipDef(shipType).mBodyDef);
```

I'm getting an error:

```
expression must have class type
```

on the call to CreateBody.

I've tried every arrangement of the 'address of' operator I can think of and I've been all up and down google and stack overflow.

*edited to include "b2BodyDef mBodyDef;"*

Comment: I had the wrong line in the shipDef struct.

mBodyDef isn't a pointer, the function library that uses it works that way.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

If `getShipDef` returns a pointer you have to use the `->` operator to access its members:

```
mPhysicsBody = physicsWorld->CreateBody(
     Game::getInstance()->getShipDef(shipType)->mBodyDef
);
```

If `a` is a pointer the expression `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b` so in your case you could have also written

```
mPhysicsBody = physicsWorld->CreateBody(
     (*(Game::getInstance()->getShipDef(shipType))).mBodyDef
);
```

Comment: Nitpick: The equivalence is true for plain old pointers and sane classes. But the language doesn't stop you from having `operator->` and `operator*` doing completely unrelated things.